# Problem with sending response data above 8KB

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a backend stack like that:

- Firebase Cloud Functions
- Node.js 10.19
- Express 4.17.1

I have a function there that generates an array that:

- has 50 objects
- is 8KB
- takes 6.7 seconds to generate

Whenever I'm sending this data as a response I get `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` in my browser and 'Bad string' error in Postman (somehow my JSON is cut at the end).

Right now I figured that if I cut my array to:

- 45 objects
- suddenly it's 2KB in size
- and takes 1.9 seconds to generate.

No, there is nothing different about last 5 objects.

I think it has something to do with size, but 8KB seems a bit too small to generate such big trouble.

After a long research it turned out there is [long known Node.js bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13391) (like for 3 years), but it seems it's still not resolved. It's hard to believe that problem still exists and I'm sure there are workaround for that which is what I want to ask for. It's hard to believe for me that it's timeout issue if second example I provided finishes in ~2 seconds.

Comment: Taking almost 7s to generate a hunk of JSON seems like a long time. Reducing the size of the hunk by 10% and saving 66% of the time suggests an inefficient algorithm. Please [edit] your question to show some code about how you generate the response.And remember: string concatenation isn't efficient. `let s = ""; for(let i=0; i<10000; i++){s += i.toString()}; ` is an O(n**2) operation.

Comment: The thing is algorithm is doing the very same work. I just use `slice()` after all the work has been done, right before sending it back, at the end.